# Why is “in the catching of” wrong?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositional-phrases, gerund-vs-infinitive

In this sentence, *in the catching of* is grammatically incorrect, but I cannot tell how:

> The new system, which uses remote cameras **in the catching of** speeding motorists, may undermine the police department's authority.

Can someone explain?

Comment: They want you to use *to catch* instead, which is definitely more idiomatic. I don't see that the first one is ungrammatical, though; it's just not what native English speakers would say.

Comment: @PeterShor So there is no concrete rule for this I assume :)

Comment: The rule (I believe) is that some gerunds are "more nounlike" than others, and you should only use a "less nounlike" gerund in a phrase like this if there are no good alternative ways to say it. In other words, "no concrete rule".

Comment: @Peter: I wouldn't put it that strongly. There are over 1000 instances of [*the catching of criminals*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+catching+of+criminals%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) in Google Books, and that one is fine by me. Admittedly there are only 4 instances of [*the catching of speeding {xxx's}*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+catching+of+speeding%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) - but it's just a bit "clunky", not something that non-natives simply wouldn't say at all.

Comment: @Zach: Perhaps you should have asked this on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), where you could learn all about the [*"**horror aequi**" principle*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/15380/126) which I think is central to your question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks! So basically one does not want two phrases ending in "ing" to be adjacent  -- catching and speeding.  Putting to catch would solve this problem

Comment: You’ve started with a false premise — the notion that there is anything ungrammatical about that sentence — and so all answers are equally valid.  A false premise gets you nowhere, except perhaps for accusations of leading questions.

Comment: @tchrist The creators of the SAT put this in the grammar errors part of the test.  In this part of the test you have to find the incorrect part of the sentence (if there is one).  If there isn't you can choose no error.  Instead of choosing no error the creators of the test said that "in the catching of" was incorrect usage of grammar.  This was clearly is in the error section and not in the sentence improvement section, so a lot of people who put some deep thought into this test (after all its their job and colleges rely on them) consider it an error.

Comment: @ZachHoffman Well, that’s a shame then, since they are patently incorrect in that assertion.

Comment: @ZachHoffman: It's not a good construction to "test" learners, since you can clearly see competent native speakers here with a range of opinions from "perfectly okay" to "not idiomatic" (but apparently none going so far as "not grammatical"). And I personally believe that the supposed "fix" of switching ***in catching*** to ***to catch*** could significantly shift the meaning. Things that are used *in doing* something often only have a peripheral role, whereas things used *to do* something are usually central and necessary to accomplish whatever is being done.

Comment: I'm not going with "horror aequi" here, as 'The new system, which uses remote cameras in the catching of criminals' sounds equally gauche. The SATS people cannot be said to be incorrect in labelling this usage ungrammatical if they choose AHD definition '2.' _Not in accord with standard or socially prestigious linguistic usage._ But they should make sure that they define terms before they ask questions about grammar (and I bet they don't); it's not the definition most people here recognise as standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase "...which uses remote cameras in the catching of speeding motorists..." is **not** grammatically incorrect. It is, grammatically, just fine. However, the phrase "the catching of" is somewhat convoluted --- it would be equally correct if you were to write "...which uses remote cameras to catch speeding motorists...", which would be, in most contexts, preferable as it is clearer and easier to parse.

You may even want to consider using the word "apprehend" rather than "catch".

Comment: Hmm, on the SAT this is under the grammar errors section so it considers the phrase to be a grammar error.

Comment: @ZachHoffman one thing that can be confusing about the SAT is that there may be multiple *technically correct* answers, particularly in the reading section. However, they want you to choose the **most correct** option.

While "the catching of" is perfectly grammatically correct, it is clear that "to catch" is simply preferable. That's why "to catch" is the "right" answer.

Comment: Having to think in terms of *the most correct answer* rather than just *the correct answer* may take a little bit of time getting used to.

Comment: @ZachHoffman Then ask the makers of the test what ***they*** want you to put there and why. There is no error in that sentence, so this is all wasted effort.

Comment: @tchrist Unfortunately I don't know any of the test maker so I was asking the community to explain this to me :) 

(isn't this what the stack exchange is for?)

Comment: Sadly, there is no concensus on what 'ungrammatical' actually means (see definitions at AHD). By one definition, the sentence in question is grammatical, but using the other, it is ungrammatical. The SATS people are duty bound to explain what they mean by 'ungrammatical'.